# Implementing sampling & data mining algorithms in Hadoop

Tags: java, algorithm, hadoop, data-mining, sampling

The current implementation involves *sampling of large input transactional file* and then finally applying the 'FP growth algorithm' to this sampled data for data mining. However, it has its limitations and I would like to implement this on a larger scale.
The transactional file is sampled according to following sampling methodologies (based on user response) :

1. Random sampling
2. Systematic sampling
3. Stratified sampling
4. Cluster sampling
5. Finding associations from Sampled Transactions (FAST) algorithm.

The goal is to implement it in Hadoop for *parallel processing* and support for large input data file. Any pointers how do I achieve this in Hadoop or any other open source distributed processing framework?

Answer (score 1):

The question here mostly algorithmic and not technical. We need to find parallel approach to the algorithm and then translate it into MapReduce paradigm. Only then we can use Hadoop to run the process in parallel. 
I think that for your algorithm relevant paralleled version is: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~echang/recsys08-69.pdf